# nginx set expired header on files with query string

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My files look like this:

/js/jquery.js?ad886e4

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|svg|mp3) {
    expires 365d;
}
```

But the expired headers are not set, how can i set the expired headers to files with a query string.

Comment: The request is probably matching a different location block - a request will only match one. As such, please add your whole server block to the question. (The query string is not the reason for not matching the rule in the question)

Comment: Additionally, `location` directive checked the normalized URI which doesn't contain query string at all. Regex locations are checked from first to last, try to move this location upward.